# why does parts of my objects disappear when moved outside of "beam"

Tags: clipping

I created this scene a while back and I don't remember adjusting any settings involving clipping.

But there is a clipping "beam", and everything outside of it gets clipped away. The beam is not connected to the camera.

What is that "beam", and where is the settings for it? - any help, is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *Clipping Border* (which allows you to limit the view), try <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to enable or disable.

Comment: That was it Thanks a lot
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html